# Java if no item is selected in JComboBox then print a statement

Tags: java

**EDITED**

What im trying to do is when no item is selected in a JComboBox it would set a label text to "no item selected". This is what i tried but it did not work because by default if no item is selected it will auto select the first item in the array[0]

**Example**

```
if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() >-1)
{
    label.setText(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
}
else
    label.setText("No Item is Selected");
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also, your code is way too long to illustrate the problem you're having, and it's not correctly indented, making it very hard to read.

Comment: TL; DR; please post [mcve]

Comment: @dexter - Keep your 0th item as `Select Item` or a blank item; check if the default item is this 0th item, and then use the modified code on the action event method of your button! Modification needed -> `comboBox.getSelectedIndex() >0`

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful -  Thank you that solved the problem

Comment: 'No item selected' does not throw an exception, so there is no exception to be caught. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You can't 'return a statement', or 'print a statement' either. Still unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP the question have been solved thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I set my first index in my string array as "-" so if none is selected by default its "-".

```
if(comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("-"))
{
    label.SetTest("No Item is Selected");
}
else if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex() > 0)
    label.SetText(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
```